# How to config ptpython when embedding in an app

Tags: ptpython

I am using PTPython to interactively debug my app.  When embedding PTPython in my app, how do I support reading the PTPthon config file?

According to the [example PTPython config file](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython/blob/master/examples/ptpython_config/config.py), in Linux the PTPython config file should be located at the path `~/.config/ptpython/config.py`

I'm embedding PTPython using the following:

```
from ptpython.repl import embed
embed(globals(), locals(), vi_mode=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [example](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/ptpython.ipython.embed/), I've found the following will read my PTPython config file:

```
from ptpython.repl import embed, run_config

def configure(repl):
    config_path = pathlib.Path("/home/me/.config/ptpython/config.py")
    run_config(repl, config_path)

history_path = pathlib.Path("/home/me/.ptpython/history")
embed(globals(), locals(), vi_mode=False, configure=configure, history_filename=history_path)
```